# How do I select rows from one table as CSV and insert into another table based on a key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables  `testa` and `testb`.

```
mysql> select * from testa;
+------+-------+
| id   | dcac  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | hello |
|    2 | world |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from testb;
+------+------+
| a_id | x    |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    1 | b    |
|    1 | b    |
|    1 | c    |
|    2 | x    |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I add a column (`x_list`) to `testa` such that it's the comma-seperated list of `x`s from `testb` wherever `testa.id` is `testb.a_id`

So the output I'm expecting is somewhat like this -

```
+------+-------+--------+
| id   | dcac  | x-list |
+------+-------+--------+
|    1 | hello | a,b,b,c|
|    2 | world | x      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

I tried using some complex `join` statements and I looked at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat (did not really understand much)

But I'm not able to proceed. What do I do?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you not understand about group_concat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT testa.id, testa.dcac, GROUP_CONCAT(testb.x)
FROM testb
INNER JOIN testa ON testb.a_id = testa.id
GROUP BY testb.a_id
```

You can see result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28887/2/0